# How can i get the datas from rows under of a column

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio, web-testing

Hi guys i am having problem with get the datas in rows. i want the get the datas from under Name Surname column.

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Login Page/Login'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Home Page/patientListTable'), 5)
WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Home Page/patientList_Row'), 5)

List<WebElement> rows = WebUI.findWebElements(findTestObject('Object Repository/Home Page/patientList_Row'),5)
assert rows.size() > 1
int numberOfRows = rows.size()
println "numberOfRows=${numberOfRows}"

for (WebElement row in rows) {
    WebElement name = row.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-field='nameSurname']"))
    assert name != null
    println "name=${name.getText()}"
}
```

this is my code and this is the html code sorry for the censor. the xpath in devs console is for the rows and it is correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGVh.png)

when i execute the code above it only prints NAME SURNAME in the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtuWz.png)

i wanted to try get the rows data from the column but i get only the Column name in the console

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. It's incomplete, could you provide us a minimal/runnable code?